# MySQL Junction Table as Foreign Key?

Tags: mysql, schema

I have several tables: `company`, `customer`, `company_has_customer`, and `transaction`.

`company_has_customer` is a many-to-many junction table using the PKs of `company` and `customer` as its PK.

In almost all situations throughout the database, both the `company` and `customer` are used to identify a record (e.g. in the `transaction` table).

My question is whether I should create the foreign key in the `transaction` table to point to `company_has_customer` or to the two tables (`company`, `customer`) individually?

I believe it would be best for referential integrity to send those FKs through `company_has_customer` to ensure that `transaction` records are only inserted if there is a relationship between the company and the customer.  Are there any standards or conventions to support my hunch?

My second question is doing the lookup from `transaction` to the `customer` table if the FK is actually going through the `company_has_customer` table.  There would still be an index, but should I always have to join through the `company_has_customer` table?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to enforce. If a `transaction` can take place between a `customer` and a `company` that is not in `company_has_customer` the individual foreign keys are preferable. If a `transaction` only can take place between a `customer` and a `company` that is in `company_has_customer` it is better to have a foreign key to that table.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use transaction table as warehouse table.because sometime two many references also cause low performance in getting data.
but if you are not in a production db situation which populate db with bulk data in seconds you can use those references and customers pk is important in transaction table.
your second part of question is look up from transaction to customer have nothing to do with company_has_customer this table is used when you want to know the customer belongs to which company.

Comment: I may create a secondary transaction table that is de-normalized. Is that what you mean by warehouse table?  I like enforcing data my data integrity when I can, and not simply that `customer` and `company` exist, but rather that their combination is valid in the transaction log.